Generate high resolution JPEG artifacts
I'm working on generating JPEG DCT artifacts from a high-resolution random noise texture. Due to the large size of the original image (4243x6000 pixels), I'm providing a screenshot for reference. Below is a screenshot of the input image:  I aim to achieve an output similar to the following, maintaining the same resolution as the input:
. The output image shown is a result of processing through a "deepfried" meme generator, which limits the width to 800 pixels. However, if I refrain from resizing the output, the artifacts are not added.
Could someone suggest a method, preferably using Python or Bash, PS, to generate the second image at the same resolution as the input while preserving the DCT artifacts?

@cybernetic.nomad thanks for the comment ! I tried but it looks like the artifacts only get generated if lowering the image size, the only solution that comes to my mind is to re-upscale the output to preserve them.

Probably you need to define the scale of the artifacts because the chunks a JPG produces are defined, and on a high-resolution image they will be tiny in comparison.

@Rafael thanks for your comment I'll try to dive a bit into it!

You can generate artifacts easily by exporting as JPEG and setting the quality to 0 in software such as GIMP, Photoshop, Krita, probably even ImageMagick.  However, I feel the image you are showing has had more done to it, possibly a levels adjustment to intensify the contrast. I did this in GIMP. It's still the same resolution.
